# Unit test fails on build from Intellij but passes from terminal

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, build

I have a big java project. Using maven to automate the build and manage dependencies and JUnit for the unit testing.

When i'm running `mvn clean install` from Intellij the build fails because of one unit test that fails.
The test succeeds when ran manually.

Also, executing `mvn clean install` from the terminal succeeds. (all tests pass)

I'm not sure where to look for the problem here.

Thanks!

Comment: normally there is output from the build process that states exactly what the problem is

Comment: IntelliJ runs unit tests in the same JVM for performance reasons. Try changing this in settings

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If i'm using `mvn clean install` inside intellij's terminal, should this still be affected from those settings?

Comment: @Stultuske I see which specific test fails. The problem is that it does not fail when ran manually from the IDE.

Comment: I don’t know. Your description is so vague that nobody can analyze what is the problem except mentioning a fundamental difference.  Please reconsider actually communicating what you see…

Comment: @nirst normally, the logs should also tell WHY it fails. it's possible that your IDE, when you run the test manually, doesn't use the same config as when your maven install runs them

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a problem like this. Everything worked well when I ran the tests on command line. But on IntelliJ, not a single test ran because of an error during `@Before`. This was the error `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException` but this did not mean anything.

The solution was to edit the "Run/Debug Configurations". Had to change the Build and run option to use JDK8, it was using JDK15.

Apparently IntelliJ isn't intelligent enough.